# Flutter layout logic

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Hi everyone, I am tasked to create this UI in flutter. What is the best practice that you may suggest in building this, as to what widget to use and in what order. Initially, this form  got its data from previous search page. This layout is from a concept drawing referenced from an existing application.

Thank you.

Comment: Send me 500 bucks and I'll build it for you. Otherwise, try yourself and then ask some targeted question. SO is not a "make my assignment for free" kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks @Ber, I understand your point. What i am looking for is the logic. Like, 

Header ( Column, textfield, padding 10 )
Body ( ExpansionTile )
Bottom ( Row(Buttons)